# Most Efficient way to create a symmetric matrix

Tags: r, loops

I have the following matrix/ dataframe:

```
> e
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  0  2  3  4  5
2  0  0  6  8 10
3  0  0  0 12 15
4  0  0  0  0 20
5  0  0  0  0  0
```

In this case N=5 (number of rows = number of columns). I would like to fill in the missing values in this symmetric matrix (e[1,2]=e[2,1] etc.). Is there a most efficient way to fill in the missing values (N the matrix size in my case quite big)? Is there a better way than nested loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for completion I would like to also show this technique. The addition of the transpose will not work if the lower part of the matrix (under the diagonal) has values filled in, as it will add them to the upper part of the matrix.

Using the Matrix package we can create a sparse Matrix, which in case of creating the symmetric of a big matrix would require much less memory and even speed it up.

In order to create a symmetric sparse matrix from matrix `e` we would do:

```
library(Matrix)
rowscols <- which(upper.tri(e), arr.ind=TRUE)
sparseMatrix(i=rowscols[,1],    #rows to fill in
             j=rowscols[,2],    #cols to fill in
             x=e[upper.tri(e)], #values to use (i.e. the upper values of e)
             symmetric=TRUE,    #make it symmetric
             dims=c(nrow(e),nrow(e))) #dimensions
```

Output:

```
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"

[1,] .  2  3  4  5
[2,] 2  .  6  8 10
[3,] 3  6  . 12 15
[4,] 4  8 12  . 20
[5,] 5 10 15 20  .
```

Microbenchmark:

Let's make a function to make a symmetric Matrix out of a matrix (copies the upper part of matrix to the lower by default):

```
symmetrise <- function(mat){
  rowscols <- which(upper.tri(mat), arr.ind=TRUE)
  sparseMatrix(i=rowscols[,1], 
               j=rowscols[,2], 
               x=mat[upper.tri(mat)], 
               symmetric=TRUE, 
               dims=c(nrow(mat),ncol(mat)) )  
}
```

And test:

```
> microbenchmark(
e + t(e),
symmetrise(e),
e[lower.tri(e)] <- t(e)[lower.tri(e)],
times=1000
)
Unit: microseconds
                                  expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
                              e + t(e)   75.946   99.038  117.1984  110.841  134.9590   246.825  1000 a  
                         symmetrise(e) 5530.212 6246.569 6950.7681 6921.873 7034.2525 48662.989  1000   c
 e[lower.tri(e)] <- t(e)[lower.tri(e)]  261.193  322.771  430.4479  349.968  395.3815 36873.894  1000  b
```

As you can see `symmetrise` is actually much slower than `e + t(e)` or `df[lower.tri(df)] <- t(df)[lower.tri(df)]` but at least you have a function that automatically symmetrises a matrix (takes the upper part and creates the lower by default) and in case you have a big matrix where memory is an issue, this might come in handy.

P.S. Wherever you see a `.` in the Matrix this represents a zero. By using a different system a sparse Matrix is a kind of 'compressed' object making it more memory efficient.

Comment: You need to transpose the upper triangular part of the matrix `t(e)[lower.tri(e)]`, as I did in my answer, or you will not get the same result that `e + t(e)`

Comment: @mpalanco Yes you re right. I didn't notice this. Avi I would change the accepted answer if I were you. There is no point in having this answer here if I would switch to mpalanco's

Comment: You're very kind. I did the same at first and realised it wasn't symmetrical. Good idea to post the benchmark. Thank you.

Comment: I changed my answer to a memory efficient solution and created an function that converts a matrix into a symmetric one. I still think that @mpalanco 's idea is the best for small to medium matrices but this should work great if you have memory restrictions or a big matrix.

Answer (score 6):

Also for speed:

```
2*symmpart(as.matrix(e))
```

Here's a benchmark:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                      expr      min       lq        mean    median        uq       max neval
                                  e + t(e)  572.505  597.194  655.132028  611.5420  628.4860  8424.902  1000
                             symmetrise(e) 1128.220 1154.562 1215.740071 1167.0020 1185.6585 10656.059  1000
 e[lower.tri(e)] <- e[upper.tri(e, FALSE)]  285.013  311.191  350.846885  327.1335  339.5910  8106.006  1000
                2 * symmpart(as.matrix(e))   78.392   93.953  101.330522  102.1860  107.9215   153.628  1000
```

It can get this speed because it creates a symmetric matrix directly.

Comment: In the `Matrix` package, `x == symmpart(x) + skewpart(x)` for all square matrices

Comment: This is a good answer and actually the fastest (i have upvoted) but again this only works in the case where the lower or upper parts are all zero and only then. As it says in the description the matrix is calculated as `(x + t(x))/2`.

Answer (score 5):

```
df[lower.tri(df)] <- t(df)[lower.tri(df)]
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  0  2  3  4  5
2  2  0  6  8 10
3  3  6  0 12 15
4  4  8 12  0 20
5  5 10 15 20  0
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V2 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), V3 = c(3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(4L, 8L, 12L, 0L, 
0L), V5 = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
e + t(e)
```

Adding the matrix and the transpose of that matrix, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. But I would like to do it in the most efficient way (minimum time).

Comment: I am not sure if that way is the most efficient way, but it should be better than nested loops I guess?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken this is a direct appeal to BLAS... so if you want more speed go to C/Julia/Fortran

Comment: Is there a way to use BLAS in R for this case?

Comment: R uses BLAS. A [basic search](https://www.google.com/search?q=blas+r&rlz=1CAASUF_enUS655US655&oq=blas+r&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.632j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) suggests you [may get some improvement](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/) by changing the default BLAS, [ATLAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665403/r-detection-of-blas-version)

Comment: For reference, [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/be7197fd993053920d3e582fd685894e31ae8c56/src/main/array.c) is the source code where `t.default` is implemented in C (as `do_transpose`).