# There is a huge difference in execution time for xgboost in Windows and Ubuntu Linux

Tags: r, linux, windows, ubuntu, xgboost

I have a very small dataframe with 405 rows and 45 columns. All the columns are numerical variables. I want to solve a regression model on the dataset using `xgboost` library in R. For that, I have the following piece of code:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(xgboost)
    df = read_csv('df.csv')
    y_train = as.matrix(df$y)
    x_train = as.matrix(df[, 2:45])
    params = list(max_depth = 6, eta = 0.05, subsample=0.8, objective = "reg:squarederror")
    xgb_train = xgb.DMatrix(data = x_train, label = y_train)

    s1 = Sys.time()
    model = xgb.train(data=xgb_train, nrounds = 100, params = params)
    s2 = Sys.time()
    print(s2-s1)
```

When I run this piece of code in a Windows computer with Intel Xeon processors and 128 GB of RAM it takes around 0.5 seconds

When I run it in a Ubuntu machine with Intel Xeon processors and 256 GB of RAM it takes 1.12 minutes.

Why may it be running so slow in Ubuntu? Is there a way to get it to run faster?

Anyone interested can download the dataset I mention here: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/JenUAz2c#link

Comment: Almost certainly related to which linear algebra libraries R is linked to - see [R detection of Blas version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665403/r-detection-of-blas-version)

Comment: As @SamR already stated try different BLAS/LAPACK. However be careful with fancy BLASs that use multiple cores when working on a server, they tend to use ALL cores, can actually reduce performance in combined use with multi-threading, and can reduce team love. On Linux I recommend using flexiblas to quickly switch between different BLASs. Cheers!